# Gulp-wrap Alternative

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-wrap

I have an existing working project with gulp workflow. Everything runs perfectly fine. My gulp uses this:

- browser-sync@2.0.1
- gulp@3.8.11
- gulp-angular-templatecache@1.5.0
- gulp-autoprefixer@2.1.0
- gulp-concat@2.4.3
- gulp-less@2.0.3
- gulp-minify-css@0.3.13
- gulp-minify-html@0.1.8
- gulp-rename@1.2.0
- gulp-sourcemaps@1.3.0
- gulp-uglify@1.1.0
- gulp-util@3.0.3
- gulp-watch@4.1.1
- gulp-wrap@0.10.1
- minimist@1.1.0

So, I decide it use it on new project for my team. I copy `gulpfile.js`, `package.json` to the new project folder and run `npm install`. Everything is downloaded as usual. But when I try to run my gulp task, I came into this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise> has no method 'done'
at DestroyableTransform._transform (E:\www\myproject\node_modules\gulp-less\index.js:68:8)
```

After some testing I found that that the problem is actually caused by `gulp-wrap`, which it can be solved by:

1. Copy the `gulp-wrap` folder from the old project and override the new one
2. Comment out / remove all `gulp-wrap` usage and also the require() of it from gulpfile.js

At first I thought it is caused by new version issue. So, I specifically specify the version in `package.json`. But after run the `npm install`, the same problem occur.

So, when I look into my gulpfile, there is only one place that uses `gulp-wrap`.

```
wrap('(function(){"use strict"; <%= contents %>\n})();')
```

Is there anyway I can do the wrapping for this without using `gulp-wrap` to avoid that problem from occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that gulp-insert (https://github.com/rschmukler/gulp-insert) does the job as well and so far I did not experience the problem I am facing with gulp-wrap.

It can be done with this:

```
.pipe(insert.wrap('(function(){"use strict";', '\n})();'))
```